# Solve the differential equation 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y' = \frac{y}{\sin x} + \tan \frac {x}{2} $$

So from the beginning I do 
$$y' - \frac{y}{\sin x} = \tan \frac {x}{2} $$
Now I should equal it to 0, shouldn't I?
$$y' - \frac{y}{\sin x} = 0 $$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}   = \frac{y}{\sin x} $$
$$ dx\sin x=ydy$$
$$ \cos x=\frac{y^2}{2} $$
$$y=\sqrt{2\cos x}$$
And now i have problem with that derivative, is there any short way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the integrating factor method. You have an ODE of the form y'(x)+p(x)y(x)=q(x). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor